# Edit the HTML in MyBB theme, to replace buttons

Tags: forum, mybb

I'm trying to do this https://github.com/stewartiee/Steam-OpenID--MyBB-/issues/17 So I replace the normal register and login buttons. But how do I edit html in MyBB,? It seems like I can only edit the themes CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instructions below assume you already have the Apart 1 theme installed.

- Log in as an administrator on your board.
- Click on "Templates & Style" along the header bar in the admin panel
- Click "Templates" on the left navigation menu
- Click "Apart 1 Templates" in the main area
- Click on "Header Templates", it should expand to show 5 (or so) options
- Click on the one named `header_welcomeblock_guest`
- Add the code block in the Github issue to to the end of line 12 (but inside the `span`), or modify that line as needed with the code block from Github